# Does paperclip work with SimplyStored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, couchdb, paperclip

Rails 3.0.0, paperclip 2.3.3, simplystored 0.3.6.

I'm using simplystored so i can use couchdb, but i am thinking that simplystored doesn't work with paperclip.

I've tried using paperclip as a gem [via bundler] as well as a plugin, and I get the same error regardless:

undefined method `has_attached_file' for Video:Class.

Any way to get these working?

Answer (score 0):

Here is someone that [did it with Couch:Rest](http://forrst.com/posts/Storing_paperclip_attachments_as_CouchDB_attachm-1bQ). I suppose something similiar could be possible with simplystored. Anyways - I am diving into the same kind of challenge as you now so I will come back with more insights in a while.